# Which is the best zigbee mode for my following requirements?

Tags: zigbee

I am a beginner in **Zigbee**. I wanna create a mesh network of Zigbee modules in which all nodes can communicate with each other.

I found that Zigbee can be operated in different modes and each modes have its own features. I want to know that which mode will provide an effortless communication in real time applications. We want to build a system that automatically connects to the neighboring Zigbee modules and establishing a communication path to each other.

Is anyone knows about it,please give me the answer to clarify my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both
 **Transparent mode** has limited functionality and not suitable for larger networks but
**API mode** allows you to form larger networks and is more appropriate for creating sensor networks to perform tasks such as collecting data from multiple locations, controlling devices remotely, automating your home or for real time systems.